# connect from an app to a php-script and retrieve the data?

Tags: php, android, web-services, qt, http

I am writing an app for Android in Qt/QML that needs to synchronize with an MySQL database.

I will use a php script for the communication between the server and the mobile device.

But what I dont understand is how to connect to and retrieve data from a php-webservice.

How can I connect from an app to a php-script and retrieve the data from the queries that the php-script queries to the sql server?

I dont need a full explanation, just a bit of direction. I am not asking to be spoonfed.

How are you supposed to interact with the script?

Do you need to send some kind of string through http? Is it even possible to send strings from and to a server through http? If so, how? Do you input data inside a URL or something like that? If so, is the php script supposed to receive the request and can it parse the url?

Just a small description on how this interaction works would be apreciated

Comment: Read into ``QNetworkRequest()``

Comment: Or see http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq23-web-service.html

Comment: thnx guys, ill look into it!

Comment: nice! i managed to get it working using QNetworkRequest()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Downloader::doDownload() 
{ 
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this); 
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*))); 
    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://bogotobogo.com"))); 
}

void Downloader::replyFinished (QNetworkReply *reply) 
{ 
    if(reply->error()) { qDebug() << "ERROR!"; 
        qDebug() << reply->errorString(); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        qDebug() << reply->header(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader).toString();
        qDebug() << reply->header(QNetworkRequest::LastModifiedHeader).toDateTime().toString();
        qDebug() << reply->header(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader).toULongLong();
        qDebug() << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
        qDebug() << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpReasonPhraseAttribute).toString(); 
        QFile *file = new QFile("C:/Qt/Dummy/downloaded.txt"); 

        if(file->open(QFile::Append)) 
        { 
            file->write(reply->readAll()); 
            file->flush(); 
            file->close(); 
        } 

        delete file; 
    } 

    reply->deleteLater(); 
}
```